# Proper Way To Upload FCMToken to Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a chat app and I am almost done with it, but I have an issue with storing the user's FCM token to firestore. When I store the token, it only stores one token at a time. So whatever the current token is correlates to the current user that is logged in.

Is there a way to check if the current token exists, and if it does, don't do anything, but if it doesn't add it to the list?

I've tried different ways to do it but I can't seem to figure it out. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        if let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken {
            let usersRef = db.collection("users_table").document(userID)
            usersRef.setData(["fcmToken": token], merge: true)
            
        }
```

Comment: What list are you referring to?  Your code is attempting to write a single string value to a field called "fcmToken".  There are no lists here that I can see.  I suggest thinking carefully about what you want the result to be, and explain in more detail what isn't working the way you expect with the code you have so far.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what I am doing wrong then. The way I have my current collection set up is that whenever the user opens the app, the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions uploads the users_token to the users_table collection. The issue is I am not making a list of users_tokens, I am just writing a single value to the collection, so every time another user opens the app, the fcmToken gets replaced. Thanks for that explanation. I am a junior in computer engineering with a focus in embedded systems, so I'm not the best at software design. This is just a fun little project for my friends. Thanks!

Comment: I would like to come back and say thank you for the advice about thinking carefully about what I want my result to be! I have everything working perfectly now! Thanks!